# vsphere web client: Error while activating extension vsphere.core.controlcenter.domainView

Tags: vmware-vsphere

After logging in web client all users are getting the same message box including:

Error

```
Failed to navigate to desired location.
Error details: Error while activating extension vsphere.core.controlcenter.domainView.
Invalid domain view id: vsphere.core.controlcenter.domainView
```

Error Stack

```
Error: Invalid domain view id: vsphere.core.controlcenter.domainView
  at com.vmware.vsphere.client.views.app::AppViewMediator/showDomainView()
  at com.vmware.vsphere.client.views.app::AppViewMediator/set _1616001040globalViewSpecs()
  at com.vmware.vsphere.client.views.app::AppViewMediator/set globalViewSpecs()
  at PropertyInjectionJob/injectNonArrayCollectionTypeProperty()
  at PropertyInjectionJob/injectCollectionTypeProperty()
  at PropertyInjectionJob/injectObjectSet()
  at PropertyInjectionJob/onObjectsRetrieval()
  at com.vmware.aspectfw.extensibility::DeclarativeExtensibilityManager$/filterUsingSpecAndInvokeCallback()
  at com.vmware.aspectfw.extensibility::DeclarativeExtensibilityManager$/filterAndNotify()
  at com.vmware.aspectfw.extensibility::DeclarativeExtensibilityManager/onExtObjsCreated()
  at ExtensionObjCreationJob/onObjectCreation()
  at com.vmware.extensionfw::CallbackUtil$/callback()
  at com.vmware.extensionfw::ExtensionManager/onExtensionObjectsCreated()
  at com.vmware.extensionfw::CallbackUtil$/callback()
  at ObjectsCreator/onObjectCreated()
  at com.vmware.extensionfw::CallbackUtil$/callback()
  at com.vmware.extensionfw::ExtensionObjectFactory/onExtensionObjectParsed()
  at com.vmware.extensionfw::CallbackUtil$/callback()
  at com.vmware.extensionfw::ExtensionObjectParser/onObjectDeserialized()
  at com.vmware.flexutil::MxmlDeserializer/onThreadTerminated()
  at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
  at com.vmware.flexutil::PseudoThread/terminate()
  at com.vmware.flexutil::PseudoThread/onTimer()
  at com.vmware.flexutil::PseudoThread/start()
  at com.vmware.flexutil::MxmlDeserializer/xmlToObjectAsync()
  at com.vmware.extensionfw::ExtensionObjectParser/parse()
  at com.vmware.extensionfw::ExtensionObjectFactory/getExtensionObject()
  at ObjectsCreator/onResourceModulesLoaded()
  at com.vmware.flexutil::ResourceLoader/onModuleLoad()
  at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
  at ResourceEventDispatcher/moduleInfo_readyHandler()
  at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
  at ModuleInfoProxy/moduleEventHandler()
  at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
  at ModuleInfo/readyHandler()
  at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
  at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/update()
  at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/docFrameHandler()
  at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/docFrameListener()
```

I'm using vcenter server appliance 5.5 U3.

It started today, before webclient was working a litle bit slow but correctly. Now, users can't do anything. Because after this message nothing more happens. Tested on various browsers, same behavior. Do you have any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have turned off vcenter server. Added more RAM memory,and turned it on. After 30mins I did restart of webclient service. Then web client started to work properly, without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

two days ago i found this post and adding more ram to a VM the issue was solve.

Today appears again the same error, and the VM status graphics shows the vCenter VM only uses 10 GB of 16 GB configured.

Searching in google i found other solution to enter to vCenter vSphere

If you use Spanish or other languaje, the error appears... i think this issue appears when you use a additional connector (in my case was Veeam... apparently this connector has issues with Spanish)

The solution now was put the IP/machine-name with more info.

https://x.x.x.x/vsphere-client/**?locale=en_US**

Regards !!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cache and restart the browser.

Comment: This didn't help. That was first what was made. But all users are affected. No one can use his account via webclient. I have also restarted service dedicated for webclient, and also whole vcenter server was restarted. Issue still persists.